# How to get all possible combinations of the number if we have divide the number in equal number of groups

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

Suppose we 6 balloons. we only can make the groups as follows:

1. a group of 3 balloons in each group : total 2 groups
2. a group of 2 balloons in each group : total 3 groups
3. a group of 1 balloon in each group :  total 6 groups

Suppose we 10 balloons. we only can make the groups as follows:

1. a group of 5 balloons in each group : total 2 groups
2. a group of 2 balloons in each group : total 5 groups
3. a group of 1 balloon in each group :  total 10 groups

I am not able to write a C language code for it.

Comment: You only need to go up to the square root - each factor gives the complementary factor >= square root.

Answer (score 1):

With this code, you will be able to display all the divisors of your number :

```
int main()
{
long int n,i;
cout<<"Enter the number: ";
cin>>n;
cout<<endl<<"Divisors of "<<n<<" are";

for(i=1;i<=n;++i)
{
if(n%i==0)
cout<<" "<<i;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: And in the tagged C...?